# Overcoming high (stacking) resistance skills with ranged weapons

Tags: combat, star-wars-d6

In Star Wars D6 a character that was hit in combat rolls an resistance<sup>1)</sup> roll against the damage roll of the opponents weapon.

The issue has come up that it seems to be a lot easier for characters to stack resistance bonuses to get a fairly high value than it is to increase damage output<sup>2)</sup>.

- It is rather easy to get a fresh character with `6d` resistance (e.g. a *Wookie* with `6d` in Strength, or a *Barabel* with their natural scale armour). If such a character straps on some body armour / combat suit, resistance values of `7d` and beyond can be reasonably achieved.
- In comparison, most normal portable ranged/blaster weapons cap out at `5d` damage. (With a few examples going beyond that, but those are mostly huge military-grade stationary weapons.)

Resisting `5d` damage with `7d` resistance is pretty insane and makes these characters extremely durable. This translates to an 86% chance of not being hurt when hit by such a weapon. And needing an average of 5 hits to have a >50% chance of them taking any damage *at all*.<sup>3)</sup>

**Are there any rules that allows combatants to overcome high resistance skill by their opponent, e.g. by some bonuses that stack on the *damage* of weapons?**

Note: I'm talking about ranged combat. I'm aware that for melee combat Strength + weapon damage can result in high damage rolls,

---

<sup>1)</sup> I'm unsure about the English nomenclature here, IIRC the skill is called "Absorbieren" (*to absorb*) in German.

<sup>2)</sup> Same goes for NPCs, though this isn't as much of a problem really as those rolls can be fudged if need be.

<sup>3)</sup> Don't hang me up on the math, I just played around in AnyDice.

Comment: Yeah, its a problem.  God forbid your Wookie PC is Force Sensitive.  I had one soak a blast from an imperial shuttle by raging and spending a force point.  I'll take a look when I get home.

Comment: You can blast them with heavy weaponry, but then the issue is that if the weapon gets too large, its accuracy for smaller targets drops precipitously.  You are likely never going to hit a PC with anything larger than the guns on an x-wing sized ship, and even then....  So that's not much of a solution.

Comment: Isn't this really more of a feature than a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, there are a few of ways to overcome the "soak" of a high strength using ranged attacks (if not ranged weapons per se).**

Here are some methods.  I put them in order of reasonable to "super munchkin cheeze whiz".  For some of these methods, I certainly do not endorse using them on a player's characters.  Some of them are extremely drastic, and should be used sparingly, if at all.

**Improve the Weapon**

In *Chapter 2 - Attributes and Skills*, on page 62 of the English version of the [2nd Edition rules](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Roleplaying_Game,_Second_Edition,_Revised_and_Expanded) under *Technical Skill* in the *Improving Vehicles, Vessels and Weapons* section there is a section on improving weapon damage.

> **Weapons:** Characters may wish to improve the fire control and damage for certain weapons, including personal sidearms (blaster pistols) and ordnance mounted on vessels. (The cost is based on the original cost of the weapon
>   itself, not the ship or vehicle it's mounted on.)

With a table outlying the Pip Increase, Difficulty & Cost of weapon improvement.

**Concentrate All Fire On That Super Star Destroyer**

Using the rules under the command skill on page 82 in the [rule book](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Roleplaying_Game,_Second_Edition,_Revised_and_Expanded), it is possible for characters to combine actions.  It is possible for characters to increase their damage rolls in this manner.

> If a group of characters are combining actions on a combat task, the bonus can be split between the attack roll and the damage roll.

**Spend Character Points**

pg 84 of the [rule book](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Roleplaying_Game,_Second_Edition,_Revised_and_Expanded).

> There are limits to the number of Character Points that can be spent:
>   - Two to increase the damage of an attack. (This often counts as an evil action.)

Note Force Points will only help for melee weapons, which is not the scenario you are asking about.

Not many NPCs will have Character Points, but some will - especially main villains.  And they don't typically care about doing "evil actions".

**Force Powers**

Some force powers do not use Strength to soak damage.  See page 147 of the [rule book](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Roleplaying_Game,_Second_Edition,_Revised_and_Expanded)*Injure/Kill* comes to mind as it uses *Perception* to resist.

**Use Grenades**

PCs in the center blast radius of a Thermal Detonator take 10D damage.  Even a Wookie is wary of a thermal detonator. See page 233 of the [rulebook](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Roleplaying_Game,_Second_Edition,_Revised_and_Expanded)

**Use explosives via the Demolitions Skill**

With the right explosive, a character with demolitions can dish out speeder level damage with no matching increase in difficulty in hitting a target.  See the demolition skill on page 63 of the [second edition rules](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Roleplaying_Game,_Second_Edition,_Revised_and_Expanded)

> The most common explosive is detonite, and a fist sized cube does 1D speeder-scale damage. The damage in the charts below is figured for one cube of detonite. Additional detonite cubes increase the base damage by +1D. If characters aren't using a high-grade explosive like detonite, reduce damage.

Detonite?  Really?  Oh well.

Also, under that skill

> If the character beats the difficulty [of setting an explosive to cause extra damage], he adds extra damage dice past the detonite's 1D. Find the number of points by which the character beat the difficulty.

In addition, the PCs might salvage the souped-up blaster your NPC had made if they happen to kill them.  But explosions are a one use item.

**Sic A Droid On Them**

This really is a variation on get a bigger weapon (see below).  Think of a combat droid as a mobile weapons platform.  Most combat droids from any of the sourcebooks have ranged weapons that do 7D and up.  Remember too that Droid weapons can be improved with a good droid repair roll.

**Sic A Pet On Them**

A small number of creatures have a ranged attack that can harm a wookie.  One great example is the Lava Dragon from [The Jedi Academy Sourcebook](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Jedi_Academy_Sourcebook).  Or an as yet undiscovered critter may spit poison, or even have force powers (or a simulacrum thereof.)  A particularly nasty version of a force using critter is the Dreambeast in the [Domain_of_Evil](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Domain_of_Evil) adventure.  It does mental damage that can take out a PC with weak mental stats.

**Get a Bigger Weapon**

There are the blaster equivalent of machine guns, going up to 8D for the semi-portable E-Wb Blaster.  See page 231 of the [rulebook](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Roleplaying_Game,_Second_Edition,_Revised_and_Expanded).  Other nasties can be found in the [Imperial Sourcebook](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial_Sourcebook), such as shoulder fired "field" missile launchers.

**No Seriously, Get a Bigger Weapon**

In the [rulebook](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Roleplaying_Game,_Second_Edition,_Revised_and_Expanded) beginning on Page 95, there is a discussion of weapons and targets of different scales.

> **Scale:** You may notice that a landspeeder may have a body strength of 2D, while a character can have Strength of 4D.  Does that mean that the character is tougher than the landspeeder? No!
>
> The game uses "scales" to show the differences between different sizes and types of objects. You add or subtract dice to attack rolls, dodge rolls and damage rolls to show these differences.

A character getting hit by a Walker mounted weapon does 4D extra damage.  Of course the gunner has to subtract 4D from their atack roll.  *However,* you can mount vehicles with weapons that have a blast radius.  A weapon with a blast radius of 5m does not have to worry as much about accuracy.  See page 91 of the [rulebook](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Roleplaying_Game,_Second_Edition,_Revised_and_Expanded).  For an example of this type of weapon, look in Chapter Nine -
 Combat Artillery in the [Imperial Sourcebook](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial_Sourcebook).

**Environmental Effects**

Beasts in a hard shell, or with a thick coat of fur will not do so well in hot or humid environments.  It would be perfectly reasonable to impose a penalty to Strength to such creatures stuck in such an environment.  And while not an attack per se, it can lower a PCs ability to soak damage from an attack.  If you choose this route the PCs should have every opportunity to find out about detrimental effects from a planet's climate.  Any planet that is in an astrogation chart will be tagged with know environmental hazards, and any scan of the planet should fill them in on any uncharted climate hazards to be found surface side.  Remember too that if you go this route be sure to find planets where a creature's physiology may benefit them.  It shouldn't always be "planet beats up on the wookie" day.

**Give Them A Parasite/Disease**

Similar to the environmental effects, this is a way to lower damage resistances.  A parasite or disease can sap strength, or make a carapace soft and brittle.  If you go this route, I strongly recommend you foreshadow some of the disease effects and how they might avoid catching it (if any such method exists.)  Don't just drop it on the PCs with an "Oh by the way".  There are some examples of how to use parasites in the [Truce at Bakura Sourcebook](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Truce_at_Bakura_Sourcebook)

**Use Chemical / Biological Weapons**

The Empire is not above dropping poison on Rebel Scum.  In the [Imperial Sourcebook](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial_Sourcebook) (pg 121) and in [Han Solo and the Corporate Sector Sourcebook](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Han_Solo_and_the_Corporate_Sector_Sourcebook) there are a number of Chem weapons that impose certain effects some of which are not resisted by strength, and / or reduce the strength of an attack victim.  These can be delivered by ranged weapons, from hand held flechette weapons ( In [Han Solo and the Corporate Sector Sourcebook](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Han_Solo_and_the_Corporate_Sector_Sourcebook)), to Starfighter sized canister launchers (in [Imperial Sourcebook](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial_Sourcebook) ).

**Run Them Over**

See *Ramming* on page 110 in the [rule book](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Roleplaying_Game,_Second_Edition,_Revised_and_Expanded).  Don't forget to adjust the damage for scale.

**Destroy Their Vehicle / Walker / Starship**

If they are in a vehicle, target their ride (or their driver)!  It's much easier to hit, and if you get them to have an accident you can destroy the vehicle.  This does a whopping 12D damage to the passengers (pg 112 in the [rule book](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Roleplaying_Game,_Second_Edition,_Revised_and_Expanded)). This will also scale.

**Drop A Bomb On Them**

[Orbital bombardment is no joke](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Orbital_bombardment).  Destroying a structure inhabited by a PC would probably do similar damage as destroying a vehicle.  More if they are in a high rise.  Don't forget to scale!  See ph127 for rules on bombs.

**Defenestrate**

Falling damage gets pretty bad.  Up to 9D for greater than 50m.  There are weapons and Force Powers that do "knockback" sufficient to blow a high strength character right out of a handy window.

**Space Them**

The vacuum if space is not conducive to any life.  High strength or not.

**Drop A Moon On Them**

Finally, you can always do what they did in the extended universe.  The writers (basically) [dropped a moon on Chewie to kill him](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Destruction_of_Sernpidal).  ***Warning***: expect a similar reaction from your players that the fans gave the writers.

> The Wookiee stood in the moon's trajectory, bellowed his last heroic roar, and was crushed along with the countless number of Sernpidal citizens who could not, or refused to, escape.

Seriously - don't do this though.  I still have not forgiven R. A. Salvatore.

There are probably some others, but hopefully that's enough ideas to get you started.

Comment: *"There is always a bigger blaster"* - Misheard quote attributted to Qi-Gon Jin.

Comment: YV was already bad. The galactic version of [rocks fall everyone dies](https://1d4chan.org/wiki/Rocks_fall,_everyone_dies) was just icing.

Comment: Yeah - Vector Prime made me lose my religion.